# Every continuous action $\varphi$ on $S^1\cup \{(x, 0): x\in[-1, 1]\}$ does have $(-1, 0)$ as fixed point

Tags: calculus, continuity, group-actions, topological-groups

If $X=S^1\cup \{(x, 0): x\in[-1, 1]\}$, then for every homeomorphism $F:X\to X$, $F((-1, 0))=(-1, 0)$. This implies that if $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ is a continuous action, then $\varphi(g, (-1, 0))= (-1, 0)$. Hence every continuous action $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ does have $p= (-1, 0)$ as fixed point.

But, referee of my manuscript claim that it is not true and give a continuous action on $X$ by rotations on $S^1$ and the identity map on $\{(x, 0): x\in(-1, 1)\}$.

Consider $\{ (-1-\frac{1}{n}, 0)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Take $g\in G$, then $\{\varphi(g, (-1-\frac{1}{n}, 0))\}=\{(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 0)\} $ but if $\varphi(g, (-1, 0))\neq (-1, 0)$, then
$(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 0)\to \varphi(g, (-1, 0))$ that is contradiction, because  $(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 0)\to (-1, 0)$

Is it true   every continuous action $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ does have $p= (-1, 0)$ as fixed point? please help me to know it.

Comment: What is $G$? If you do not impose any restrictions on it (e.g. connectivity) the claim will be false. And the first sentance of your question is obviously false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Thanks for your reply. Can you please give me further information? You say that the first sentence of my question is false. I think if $F:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism, then $F(p)=p$ for $p\in \{(-1, 0), (1, 0)\}$. Is this true?

Comment: If it is true, since $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ is continuous action, hence for every $g\in G$, $\varphi_g:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism. This implies that $\varphi_g(p)=p$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: As I said, it is obviously false, take $F(x,y)=(-x,-y)$. What is obviously true is that every self-homeomorphism of $X$ preserves $\{(\pm 1, 0)\}$ as a **set** since it is the set of non-manifold points of $X$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Thanks for your reply. This means that if $X$ does have only one non-manifold point $p\in X$, then $F(p)=p$ for every homeomorphism $F:X\to X$. Is it rue?

Comment: Of course......